# Outlook email is auto executing activation link

Tags: php, email, hyperlink, outlook, activation

This problem only seems to occur when opening emails from outlook.  It does not occur in Gmail.

I have created a web app that has a email base account activation.  The issue is that when I open the activation email in Outlook it automatically activates the activation link in the email.

The desired behaviour is to only activate it when the user clicks it.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour?  If so how would you fix it?

```
    <a
         style="border:1px solid #2a5db0;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;color:#2a5db0;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;width:100%;line-height:40px"
         href="LINK_HERE"
         target="_blank">
         Verify your email
     </a>
```

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: does outlook automatically activate links on other emails as well, or just the emails from your system?

Comment: It seems to work now.

I removed the link from the content, and put "Verify your email" in there instead.
Then I added "target="_blank" as an attribute. 

I arrived at this solution by inspecting the activation email link from another site that did not seem to have the issue.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 i am facing the same issue and i have similar kind of use case. The solution that worked for you is not working for me. I had to send html file as attachment and using Outlook's preview feature user would preview the html content n would click on the link. I am still looking for solution where I can directly send html in email body without href getting triggered. 
By any chance if you got another solution then please let me know.